# Mental lapse preferred to Synapse lapse?

Tags: word-usage

My friend used the term 'synapse lapse' the other day to describe what would be usually called a 'mental lapse'. Is this an acceptable term? I found no results in the Ngram viewer. It doesn't seem to be common, so was it a mistake or is it a trendy term that is slowly supplanting 'mental lapse'?

My problem with it is that I have never heard of an actual synapse 'lapsing' before in medical papers - am I being too fastidious about this? Or is a 'synapse lapse' an acceptable collocation now?

Comment: Define what you mean by acceptable- to whom and under what circumstances?

Comment: In the circumstances when most people would use 'mental lapse' - To whom? I don't necessarily mean scholars...but people who use idioms or phrases that would be found in dictionaries or even literature that uses formal language (including newspapers, books, magazines etc.).

Comment: I was looking for things like: to my professor or my friends or my boss and under circumstances like: in casual conversation, on a test or in an essay, or in a published technical journal.

Comment: Assume that I don't want to use slang and colloquialisms. And I mentioned that I am not speaking about scholars so no published journals. Would I say 'synapse lapse' in any conversation or literary context where writers or speakers are not expected to write like a scholar but still choose to speak without colloquial diction? If it helps, pretend that I am a writer for Time Magazine. Would I use 'synapse lapse' in an article if I wanted to describe someone's mental lapses - momentary cognitive dysfunctions?

Comment: I think it's an odd choice of words, no matter who uses it. One synapse not firing would hardly cause a lapse in thought since one neuron may have up to 10,000 synapses, and depolarization of a neuron usually requires input from multiple synapses. *Synapse lapse* may sound edgier, but *mental lapse* is far more accurate.

Comment: @medica Agree with you - that's why I had a problem with it!

Answer (score 1):

1) So, after I wrote this question, I found this blog (NYTimes) which does use the term. The blog documents 'lexicographical trifles' including modern terms:

http://schott.blogs.nytimes.com/2009/12/14/having-a-synapse-lapse/

It seems that 'synapse lapse' (or 'synaptic lapse') is starting to become idiomatic.

2) Looking in two dictionaries though (Macmillan and The Free Dictionary), lapse is usually applied to abstract terms i.e. cessation or interruption of 'memory', 'concentration' and 'judgement'. ...But synaptic fatigue (the official term for the short-term failure of synapses to fire neurons) is pretty much similar to the idea of a synaptic lapse.

Personally, I prefer mental lapse and synaptic fatigue.

'Synaptic lapse' is acceptable then based on the above two reasons. (I'm going to give myself a slow but well-deserved applause...unless someone objects).

Answer (score 1):

It's not an idiomatic expression in formal English.

It is a slang term/ kind of trope.

Urban Dictionary lists [synapse](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=synlapse), short for synapse lapse, thus:

> … In a phone call or voice-mail from the Ding, the lapse in time between "Hello" and the point at which the actual message begins. A synlapse is signalled by a drawn-out um. …

Presumably picked up from:
[Synapse Lapse](http://www.answers.com/topic/synapse-lapse#ixzz3DprOLx3a) (answers.com)

> Artist: C. J. Henry
>   Release Date: September 18, **2006**
>   Total Time: 42:22
>   Genre: Blues

Answer (score 0):

A search of published papers at PubMed.gov finds 295 results for "synapse lapse". A Google search will often find results for nonsense phrases, but refereed papers are written and edited with great care.

Comment: but the word 'synapse' doesn't occur together with 'lapse' in those papers. Lapse occurs with time. Thanks for looking through PubMed though and posting an answer.